# Geth: pipe is being closed (if Mist is up)

Tags: go-ethereum, mist

When I run Geth it seems to work fine:

```
"C:\users\john\appdata\roaming\mist\binaries\geth\unpacked\geth.exe"  --datadir=h:\Backup\Wallets\eth_real_data  --syncmode="light"
```

Then I start Mist (both Geth and Mist are the last ones, Geth is fully synchronized). And as soon as a new data arrives in Mist, I get,

> "The pipe is being closed"

and Mist jumps to its main page from where ever it was (say, in Contract Editor):

```
INFO [11-12|15:23:43] Imported new block headers               count=2    elapsed=14.000ms  number=4538687 hash=b6ce45:40ca0e ignored=0
INFO [11-12|15:24:57] Imported new block headers               count=2    elapsed=7.000ms   number=4538689 hash=cb6966:80abf7 ignored=0
INFO [11-12|15:25:42] Imported new block headers               count=2    elapsed=11.000ms  number=4538691 hash=a46dad:d04ab7 ignored=0
INFO [11-12|15:26:00] Imported new block headers               count=2    elapsed=6.000ms   number=4538693 hash=7667a7:3e6a94 ignored=0
ERROR[11-12|15:26:01] The pipe is being closed.

INFO [11-12|15:26:20] Imported new block headers               count=2    elapsed=6.000ms   number=4538695 hash=254aa0:66faf7 ignored=0
ERROR[11-12|15:26:20] The pipe is being closed.
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Add the argument `--ipcdisable` when executing the geth application.

Comment: It solves the problem, but additionally, I can not run Mist with this flag

Comment: It should really only be used for nodes. What arguments are you using when you run Mist? Are you running it via command-line or some other way?

Comment: I run Geth with command line above and then start Mist. And One more thing: the problem sees to be inconsistent. It can go away and return.